# jQuery .wrap() question

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having some problems with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = $("<div><h1>Bar</h1><p>Hi</p><h1>Baz</h1><p>bye</p></div>");
    foo.filter("h1,h2").map(function(id) {
        $(this).wrap('<span color="red"/>');
    });
    alert(foo.html());
});
```

This code outputs

```
<h1>Bar</h1><p>Hi</p><h1>Baz</h2><p>bye</p>
```

The span's are nowhere to be seen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second `<h1>` is closed with an `<h2>`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, but the problem still persists :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have any effect because [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) filters elements *at that level*, you could need [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get descendants like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = $("<div><h1>Bar</h1><p>Hi</p><h1>Baz</h1><p>bye</p></div>");
    foo.find("h1,h2").wrap('<span color="red"/>');
    alert(foo.html());
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/d8r4X/).  Also note you should use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for looping...but there's no need here, since you can just call [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) directly.

Comment: Holy crap I actually beat you to an answer for once :P

Comment: @Josh - I was busy making a demo :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) here, you want to use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).  Also, why are you using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var foo = $("<div><h1>Bar</h1><p>Hi</p><h1>Baz</h2><p>bye</p></div>");
  foo.find("h1,h2").wrap('<span color="red"/>');
  alert(foo.html());
});
```

[Live test](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/mRTXL/)

Answer (score 1):

First off: your markup is invalid (Baz is wrapped by an opening h1 and a closing h2). But the [.map reference](http://api.jquery.com/map/) says you need to return the value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = $("<div><h1>Bar</h1><p>Hi</p><h1>Baz</h1><p>bye</p></div>");
    var bar = foo.find("h1,h2").map(function(id) {
        return $(this).wrap('<span color="red"/>');
    });

});
```

Comment: His question had .map so I used .map. I find it strange that so many people would assume he doesn't need .map() without knowing the full scope of his project. Also: the code works (though I had forgotten to wrap the `this` in $() ).

Answer (score 0):

You need `.find()` instead of `.filter()` since the `heading` elements are nested.

```
var foo = $("<div><h1>Bar</h1><p>Hi</p><h1>Baz</h1><p>bye</p></div>");

foo.find("h1,h2").wrap('<div color="red"/>');
```

Also, I changed it to wrap using a `<div>` instead of a `<span>` since I don't think it is valid to have a `<span>` wrapped around `heading` elements.